# Formal terminology for positive and negative correlation between ability of workers for different jobs?

Tags: labor-economics, definition

Say there are two occupations - **A** and **B**, and plenty of workers. Let's pick occupation **A**, and **order workers from lowest to highest ability/productivity**. Which is the formal term to describe the situation where the aforementioned order:

1. leads also to an ordering from lowest to highest in occupation **B**? Absolute advantage? Positive correlation?
2. leads to the exact opposite ordering in **B**, i.e. from highest to lowest? Comparative advantage? Negative correlation?
3. produces no particular order in **B**?

**I am looking for formal terminology from labor economics**, but I can't find it. So far I am using absolute and comparative advantage, but that is not exactly the definition used in international trade theory. References are greatly appreciated.